# ASP MenuItem OnMenuItemClick not firing without Text/Value on MenuItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fire an OnMenuItemClick from one of my menu items, but I want the item itself to just be an image. My other items all fire properly because they have navigate URLs, but for this one I want to fire this event. Here is my item:

```
_sub_menu = new MenuItem();
_sub_menu.NavigateUrl = "";
_sub_menu.ImageUrl = "~/_image/release.png";
_sub_menu.ToolTip = "Release User";
SecureMenu.Items.Add(_sub_menu);
```

And here's the event:

```
protected void menuClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ToolTip.Equals("Release User"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what to do about this, is it not possible? I've added something as simple as an underscore to the text and the event fires just fine, even when clicking directly on the image itself.

If I have to have the text or value set, is there any way to hide it so I can maintain just showing an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, don't set the navigateUrl and use a dummy for value

```
_sub_menu = new MenuItem();
//_sub_menu.NavigateUrl = "";
_sub_menu.ImageUrl = "~/_image/release.png";
_sub_menu.ToolTip = "Release User";
_sub_menu.Value = " "; //or another dummy value
SecureMenu.Items.Add(_sub_menu);
```

Comment: This worked, I can't believe I didn't think to do this. Thanks a lot!